# Default properties for angular component decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to define default properties for an angular component in a decorator?

for example here is my component definition

```js
@Component({ 
selector: 'my-component', 
standalone: true, 
host: { class: 'flx' }, 
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, 
imports: [MyModule], 
template: `<div>My Awesome Component </div>`})
export class MyComponent {}
```

The below 3 attributes I have for most of my components

```js
standalone: true, 
host: { class: 'flx' }, 
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

I know that earlier there was the ability to create your own component decorator or use a spread operator like below

```js
const defProps = {
   standalone: true, 
   host: { class: 'flx' }, 
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
}

@Component({ 
selector: 'my-component', 
...defProps,
imports: [MyModule], 
template: `<div>My Awesome Component </div>`})
export class MyComponent {}
```

But with the latest versions of angular (16 and 17) it does not work.

Are there any options here? ideally would be good to create my component decorator with all my default logic and properties

PS. We can use CLI to create a component but this is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [NG1001: Decorator argument is not an object literal](https://angular.io/errors/NG1001)

> - To make the metadata extraction in the Angular compiler faster, the decorators @NgModule, @Pipe, @Component, @Directive, and @Injectable accept only object literals as arguments.
> - This is an [intentional change in Ivy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30840#issuecomment-498869540), which enforces stricter argument requirements for decorators than View Engine. **Ivy requires this approach because it compiles decorators by moving the expressions into other locations in the class output.**

So you need to define them individually, since Ivy/Angular compiler does not accept/interpret anything other than the literal definition!

Comment: Thank you, but this is crazy... so much manual typing... they should allow at least a spread operator..

Comment: @vitaly It must be for build optimization reasons, try doing a global replace using find all in vs code!